# Why doesn't echo work in if / else-shorthand?

Tags: php, if-statement

Consider these two php statements:

```
//version 1
echo (isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] === 'english') ? 'en' : 'de';

//version 2
(isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] === 'english') ? echo 'en' : echo 'de';
```

AFAIK, those shuld do the same thing – check if the GET-parameter `p` exists and is set to `'english'` and if so, echo `'en'`, if not, echo `'de'`. However, while the first version works as intended, the second one produces an `error: unexpected 'echo`. Why does it do that? If I wrote the normal if-else statement instead of the shorthand, both would work ... are there some limitations to how you can use the shorthand?

Comment: `echo` does not return a value - [echo is not actually a function (it is a language construct)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php). Also, [Please note that the ternary operator is an expression, and that it doesn't evaluate to a variable, but to the result of an expression](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, while the first version works as intended, the second one produces an error: unexpected 'echo. Why does it do that?

Because `?` is *not* an *“if / else-shorthand”*, but an operator. And it expects valid [*expressions*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php) as second and third operand.

Answer (score 1):

The shorthand expects an *expression* in each term, not a *statement*.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: @MoritzLost
Statement =  command to do something
expression = a value or a line of variables, operators etc that result into a value